# React native - Binding event in row of ListView

Tags: react-native

I cannot find the correct way in order to trigger the event from the class based definition under the row of the list view. Here is what i come so far

```
class SampleApp extends React.Component {

  constructor(props){
    super(props)
    this.state = {
        dataSource: ds.cloneWithRows(this._partners()),
    }

    // this._click = this._click.bind(this);
  }

 _click() {
    console.log('clicked');
  }

  _renderRow(rowData) {
    return (<TouchableHighlight onPress={() => {this._click();}}>
        <Text style={{ fontSize:18 }}>{rowData}</Text>
      </TouchableHighlight>);
  }

  render() {
    console.log('Partners: ', this._partners() )
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <ListView
         dataSource={this.state.dataSource}
         renderRow={ this._renderRow } />
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

`this` inside `onPress` is not referred to react component. How can I fix it ? This is the react playground link https://rnplay.org/apps/Xd-l3w

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this.

```
constructor(props){
  super(props)
  this.state = {
    dataSource: ds.cloneWithRows(this._partners()),
  }

  this._renderRow = this._renderRow.bind(this);
}
```

`_renderRow()` doesn't contain the scope. Rebinding it fixes the issue.

`onPress={this._click}` will also work instead of putting the `this._click` in another function.

Here's a [fork of your code](https://rnplay.org/apps/Nm5LYw).

Comment: does not work. it will give you the `null is not an object`

Comment: What version of RN are you using?

Comment: 0.21. please check the `react playround` link. Please notice that I am using the class based definition

Comment: I've forked your code and it should work now. Check it out.